# Remove class from first td on each row in a DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable with detail rows, similar to the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).  What I want to do is remove the class that shows the +/i icon for rows that don't have child data.  Should be easy, but for the life of me I can't get the syntax right to remove the class from the first td on each row.

My table.  The first column is just an icon, added by class 'dh-dtbl-details-control'.  it's added to every row.

```
var oTable = $('#dh_phleb_tblComp').DataTable({
    data: oColls.accs,
    orderClasses: false,
    "stripeClasses":['stripe1','stripe2'],
    columns:[
      {
          "class":"dh-dtbl-details-control",
          "orderable": false,
          "data": null,
          "defaultContent": ""
      },
      {data: 'collection_priority_disp'},
      {data: 'encntr_location'}
    ]
});
```

After the table's created, I'm iterating through the rows, checking for child data.  This works fine.  What I'm having problem with is identifying that td with the class in question so that I can remove it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
oTable.rows().data().each(function(value, index, id) {
    var row = oTable.row(index);
    var node = oTable.row(index).node();

    if (value.container_cnt === 0){
        alert("no containers");
        var td = $(row).find("td:first");  //doesn't seem to be right
        alert(td.className); //returning 'undefined'
        //$('td', row).removeClass("dh-dtbl-details-control"); //what I want to do
}
```

Comment: `td.className` will always be `undefined` because `td` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so it doesn't have a `.className` property. Assuming `row` is the row in question then `$(row).find("td:first").removeClass("dh-dtbl-details-control")` should work, or `$(row).find(".dh-dtbl-details-control").removeClass("dh-dtbl-details-control")`

Comment: Just right click in browser and inspect element.

Comment: What ultimately did it is $(node).find(".dh-dtbl-details_control").removeClass("dh-dtbl-details-control").  I tried it with $(row) but that didn't work.  This is kinda new to me so I need to dig in and find what is different about node vs row.

Comment: @southfanning `node` is the DOM node, `row` is the dataTable API row instance. You can do `table.row(index).nodes().to$().find(".dh-dtbl-details_control").removeClass("dh-dtb‌​l-details-control")` instead (i.e the whole thing in one expression). It is perfectly OK to answer and accept your own question. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What ultimately did it is $(node).find(".dh-dtbl-details_control").removeClass("dh-dtb‌​l-details-control").

See the comments for what pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You were close to it , in fact you gave me an idea for my Project

```
 var oTable = $('#dh_phleb_tblComp').DataTable({
 data: oColls.accs,
 orderClasses: false,
 "stripeClasses": ['stripe1', 'stripe2'],
 columns: [
     {
         "class": "dh-dtbl-details-control",
         "orderable": false,
         "data": null,
         "defaultContent": ""
     },
     {data: 'collection_priority_disp'},
     {data: 'encntr_location'}
 ],
// here you iterate each created  row and  ask for the first td and then you remove
// or add , or whatever you want to assign to this fist TD
 "createdRow": function (row, data) {
     $(row).find("td:first").removeClass('dh-dtbl-details-control');
   }
 });
```